# Multi-statement query: Syntax error when using pyodbc, but works in MySQL Workbench

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I have a query that works perfectly fine in MySQL Workbench, but when I try to run it using PyODBC, I get a syntax error. Here's the query:

```
SET @username=?;SELECT Username, CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Admins WHERE Username=@username) THEN "ADMIN"
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customers WHERE Username=@username) THEN "CUSTOMER"
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Retailers WHERE Username=@username) THEN "RETAILER"
        ELSE "UNKNOWN"
        END
        AS Type 
        FROM Users WHERE Username=@username;
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
('42000', "[42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.1(w) Driver][mysqld-8.0.31] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Username, CASE\n\t\tWHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Admins WHERE Username= @usern' at line 1 (1064) (SQLPrepare)")
```

I've tried modifying the query by declaring the @username variable using DECLARE, but that doesn't seem to work either. Any idea what might be causing this syntax error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Instead of @ username use ? And repeat for every ovcurance,maybe with mysql connector it works better odbc had some restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`BEGIN ... END` compound statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html) for multiple statements. Also, avoid double quotes for string literals and escape potential reserved words with backticks.

```sql
BEGIN
    SET @username = ?;

    SELECT 
       `Username`, 
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Admins WHERE `Username`=@username) THEN "ADMIN"
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customers WHERE `Username`=@username) THEN "CUSTOMER"
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Retailers WHERE `Username`=@username) THEN "RETAILER"
         ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
      END AS `Type`
    FROM `Users`
    WHERE `Username`=@username;
END;
```